# How do I create a view that shows how many users have subscribed to each taxonomy term?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, notifications

I have built a Drupal site with an event content type that can be tagged with one or more taxonomy terms.

Users can subscribe to these taxonomy terms and receive an automated email notification when content is created that is tagged with that term. This is achieved via the [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module.

We now require stats on how widespread the subscription service is being used, ideally I would like to create a view to show how many people are subscribed to each taxonomy term (and possibly the names of the individuals). I've tried researching this but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?